# How do you add three.js controls to an existing canvas

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm struggling with adding controls to basic three.js scene rendered in an existing canvas.
HTML code has a canvas element with id=viewport:

```
<canvas id="viewport" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
```

And here's my Javascript code (not working):

```
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();

    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(50, 640 / 480, 1, 1000);
    camera.position.y = 150;
    camera.position.z = 500;
    camera.lookAt( scene.position );

    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: viewport, antialias:true});
    renderer.setSize(640, 480);
    renderer.setClearColor (0xd3d3d3, 1);

    var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, viewport);

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh( 
        new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200, 1, 1, 1), 
        new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color : 0xff0000, wireframe: true}) 
    );
    scene.add(mesh);

    function render() {
        //mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;        
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }

    (function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        controls.update();
        render();
    })();
```

As you can see, I connect to my existing canvas here (and it works):

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas: viewport, antialias:true});
```

It renders perfectly fine when I rotate the mesh manually (https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGpqRX) but when I try to add controls it just renders black screen. Why is that so?

Comment: Infinite loop in function render

Comment: try `var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

Comment: @prisoner849 I've tried renderer.domElement before posting my question. It won't work because there's no such thing as domElement in my html.

Comment: where did you define your `viewport` var ?!

Comment: @Kaneda422 according to the docs you should still be able to access renderer's domElement (it's not an html tag, it's an object property).
As I mentioned below, a working example would help us help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to pass renderer.domElement rather than the canvas itself in your orbitControls call:

`var controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);`

[Per the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/WebGLRenderer), .domElement gets created automatically so you shouldn't have a problem doing so even if you're actually setting it with the canvas property.

[Working example based on your pen](https://codepen.io/mhazani/pen/VMyVEX)

EDIT: and, of course, include OrbitControls.js in your project. Always double check that the functionality you need is either included in core threejs or added in a script.

Comment: Here's working example without controls.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rGpqRX

Comment: Yup, renderer.domElement fixed it - see added pen in answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. As I said before, renderer.domElement was the first thing I had tried. Strange it didn't work that time.

Comment: Well, I found out why it didn't work. I thought that OrbitControls were included in three.js and that's why my html file was missing a reference to an external OrbitControls.js causing the black canvas issue.

Comment: Well that explains it:)

Comment: @AquaVitae You should mention in the answer that the link to the `OrbitControls.js` script needs to be included in html. Without it your answer, though it's accepted already, has no value.